# Pentaho Reporting Engine - How to use ItemBand in Subreport

Tags: reporting-services, pentaho

How to use ItemBand in Subreport when coding it with Pentaho Reporting Engine?

I have defined my ItemBand as follow :

```
ItemBand rowBand = new ItemBand();
TextFieldElementFactory textFactory3 = new TextFieldElementFactory();
textFactory3.setFieldname("reportname");
Element element = textFactory3.createElement();
element.setDynamicContent(true);
rowBand.addElement(element);
itemBand2.addElement(rowBand);
```

Now how do I use the ItemBand in my subreport?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks,

I was able to do it by :

```
RelationalGroup subgroup = new RelationalGroup();
GroupDataBody subgroupData = new GroupDataBody();
ItemBand itemBand = new ItemBand();
itemBand.setVisible(true);
subgroupData.setItemBand(itemBand);
subgroup.setBody(subgroupData);
subReport.setRootGroup(subgroup);

ItemBand rowBand = new ItemBand();
rowBand.setLayout(BandStyleKeys.LAYOUT_ROW);

TextFieldElementFactory subtext = new TextFieldElementFactory();
subtext.setFieldname("reportname");
subtext.setX(new Float(12.0));
subtext.setMinimumWidth(new Float(100.0));
subtext.setHeight(new Float(20.0));
Element subelement = subtext.createElement();
subelement.setDynamicContent(true);
rowBand.addElement(subelement);

TextFieldElementFactory subtext2 = new TextFieldElementFactory();
subtext2.setFieldname("reportheader");
subtext2.setX(new Float(112.0));
subtext2.setMinimumWidth(new Float(100.0));
subtext2.setHeight(new Float(20.0));
Element subelement2 = subtext2.createElement();
subelement2.setDynamicContent(true);
rowBand.addElement(subelement2);

itemBand.addElement(rowBand);

report.getReportFooter().addSubReport(subReport);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tests for the project are usually helpfull in such cases https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-reporting/blob/85b5bb6c1b970f1c2648a6bf06b7cf66b9fd0c0b/engine/core/test-src/org/pentaho/reporting/engine/classic/core/SubReportIT.java